# Compiling JNI shared library, that uses LuaJIT

Tags: c, lua, java-native-interface, luajit

I trying to make C shared library that uses LuaJIT and use it in Java via JNI. My platform is OS X (El Capitan).

`gcc -Wall -shared -fpic \
ath_lua_runtime_foundation_LuaScriptApi.c \
-ILuaJIT-2.0.4/src/ \
-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin/ \
-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/include/ \
-L. \
-lluajit \
-o libEmbeddedLua.jnilib`

It compiles correctly, but when I call it's function in Java it crashes JVM

`SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff04c5bcd0, pid=37283, tid=5891
...
Problematic frame:
C  [libluajit-5.1.2.dylib+0x11cd0]  lua_pushcclosure+0x10`

As mentioned in documentation, for OS X i should use following GCC params (and it works when I building test executable):

`-pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000`

but these params are valid only for executables, not for a shared library.

The question is how to make it work in shared library.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. This is specifically an issue on 64-bit macOS and Mike Pall discusses it [here](http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/luaL-newstate-fails-on-64bit-Mac-cant-set-linker-flags,1). If you compile a 32-bit LuaJIT from source, then things will work. To build the 32-bit LuaJIT binary, you can run the following inside the LuaJIT directory:

`CFLAGS="-arch i386" GCCFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386" make && sudo make install`